# what's the tornado ioloop, and tornado's workflow?

Tags: python, tornado

i want to know tornado's internal workflow, and have seen [this article](http://golubenco.org/?p=16), it's great, but something i just can't figure out

within the ioloop.py, there is such a function

```
def add_handler(self, fd, handler, events):
    """Registers the given handler to receive the given events for fd."""
    self._handlers[fd] = handler
    self._impl.register(fd, events | self.ERROR)
```

so what's this mean? every request will trigger add_handler or it's just triggered once when init?

every socket connect will generate a file descriptor , or it's just generated once?

what's the relationship between ioloop and iostream ?

how does httpserver work with ioloop and iostream ?

is there any workflow chart, so i can see it clearly ?

sorry for these questiones, i just confused

any link, suggestion, tip helps. many thanks :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'll see if I can answer your questions in order:

- Here `_impl` is whichever socket polling mechanism is available, `epoll` on Linux, `select` on Windows. So `self._impl.register(fd, events | self.ERROR)` passes the "wait for some event" request to the underlying operating system, also specifically including error events.

  When run, the `HTTPServer` will register sockets to accept connections on, using `IOLoop.add_handler()`. When connections are accepted, they will generate more communication sockets, which will likely also add event handlers via an `IOStream`, which may also call `add_handler()`. So new handlers will be added both at the beginning, and as connections are recieved.
- Yes, every new socket connection will have a unique file descriptor. The original socket the `HTTPServer` is listening on should keep its file descriptor though. File descriptors are provided by the operating system.
- The `IOLoop` handles events to do with the sockets, for example whether they have data available to be read, whether they may be written to, and whether an error has occured. By using operating system services such as `epoll` or `select`, it can do this very efficiently.

  An `IOStream` handles streaming data over a single connection, and uses the `IOLoop` to do this asynchronously. For example an `IOStream` can read as much data as is available, then use `IOLoop.add_handler()` to wait until more data is available.
- On `listen()`, the `HTTPServer` creates a socket which it uses to listen for connections using the `IOLoop`. When a connection is obtained, it uses `socket.accept()` to create a new socket which is then used for communicating with the client using a new `HTTPConnection`.

  The `HTTPConnection` uses an `IOStream` to transfer data to or from the client. This `IOStream` uses the `IOLoop` to do this in an asynchronous and non-blocking way. Many `IOStream` and `HTTPConnection` objects can be active at once, all using the same `IOLoop`.

I hope this answers some of your questions. I don't know of a good structural chart, but the overall idea should be fairly similar for other webservers too, so there might be some good info around. That in-depth article you linked to did look pretty useful, so if you understand enough I'd recommend giving it another go :).

Comment: "they will generate more communication sockets", are the sockets linux internal sockets (unix domain sockets) ?

Comment: @Izyy I believe they are "internet sockets" (of type socket.AF_INET in python). Wikipedia has some good info. The main listening socket will have only a recieving address+port, but each new communication socket will have both a local and remote address+port, allowing them to apply uniquely to each client connection, even though they have the same local address on the server. I'm not sure of the exact implementation details though :).