# confused about how the IOLoop in Tornado picks up the Application object

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

new to Tornado and trying to understand the fundamentals. given [their sample application](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html#structure-of-a-tornado-web-application):

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

I understand the application object has config values and RequestHandlers (basically the app behaviors) and I also understand the IOLoop to be some kind of wrapper around python3's asyncio module. Looking at [the documentation for asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) shows me this example:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await say_after(1, 'hello')
    await say_after(2, 'world')

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here `asyncio` is being told explicitly to run function `main()` whereas in the tornado example I'm not seeing where the event loop is being told to run the Application obj. How are the two associated?

been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434538/how-do-you-understand-the-ioloop-in-tornado) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072701/whats-the-tornado-ioloop-and-tornados-workflow) already

ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.listen` eventually calls into [`tornado.netutil.add_accept_handler`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/f65b1802a549bab73b4a6721bbfc47f82954d156/tornado/netutil.py#L240-L279), which registers on the current IOLoop via the `IOLoop.current()` static method.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for - ty sir!